# How can someone determine the polarization of an antenna when you have the electric field components in spherical coordinates?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism

All books define polarization using the field components in cartesian coordinates, i.e., with \$ E_x \$ and \$E_y\$. When we are in spherical coordinates though the thing becomes confusing because the unit vectors \$ \hat{r}, \hat{\theta}, \hat{\phi} \$ do not point towards constant directions and depend on \$\theta, \phi\$

Comment: You can determine the polarization of most antennas by looking at them. I feel that maybe this question is too abstract. If the antenna is long in one dimension, that is the polarization dimension. A vertical antenna is vertically polarized. A horizontal antenna is horizontally polarized. If you are in space with no up and down, then the polarization is whichever way the antenna is oriented. Or it could be circularly polarized (a good idea in space!).

Answer (score 1):

With a coordinate transformation.

It's really simple as that. You need to translate your coordinate system so that propagation is radially, and then things are directly recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary books of electromagnetism start teaching the polarization concept with plane waves. They propagate to the direction of X-axis and the electric field vector is in YZ-plane. The direction of the electric field vector is called polarization.

Plane waves come from nowhere, they travel without diverging to a constant direction. Practical waves diverge from an antenna and the equations of the fields of the waves  are simplest in spherical coordinates. An antenna sends something (more or less depending on the beam pattern) to nearly any direction. Every direction has its own rectangular base unit vector system and for me it's a superior way to show the polarization as a function of radiation direction.

You may have red that a vertical quarter wave whip antenna with ground plane generates vertically polarized wave. That's true only for those who live near the ground and collect their portion of the radiation there. For observers in higher altitudes the electric field direction differs remarkably from vertical, but one of the spherical coordinate system unit vectors matches exactly when the origin of the spherical coordinates is in the middle of the transmitter antenna.